Can your coerce your Zorostrian slave to become a Muslim?
Is there a valid interpretation set across the 4 madhabs that permit someone to coerce their Zoroastrian slave into Islam? If there is, is it required to do so or is the master given the option?

It does, thank you as always UmH! I'd like to ask though, I've heard claims that the Hanbalis allow it, is this true?

There should be no compulsion in accepting  religion according to the Quran:


There is no compulsion in matter of faith. Distinct is the way of
guidance now from error. He who turns away from the forces of evil and
believes in God, will surely hold fast to a handle that is strong and
unbreakable, for God hears all and knows everything. 2:256

